# My while loop works twice and then stops working

Tags: java, while-loop

This is a tic tac toe program, and the part you are seeing is the user and the computer decisions. I have a while loop for both and when I run it the user goes and the computer responds twice and then something happens that the computer stops making moves after the user. The user can make moves without the computer going first. I don't know why, can someone please help.

**Code**

```
            while(!userDone)
            {
                if(input == 1 && !grid.previousInputs.contains(input))
                {
                    grid.previousInputs.add(input);
                    g2.draw(X1s1); 
                    g2.draw(X1s2);
                    userDone = true;
                }
                else if(input == 2 && !grid.previousInputs.contains(input))
                {
                    grid.previousInputs.add(input);
                    g2.draw(X2s1);
                    g2.draw(X2s2);
                    userDone = true;
                }
                else if(input == 3 && !grid.previousInputs.contains(input))
                {
                    grid.previousInputs.add(input);
                    g2.draw(X3s1);
                    g2.draw(X3s2);
                    userDone = true;
                }
                else if(input == 4 && !grid.previousInputs.contains(input))
                {
                    grid.previousInputs.add(input);
                    g2.draw(X4s1);
                    g2.draw(X4s2);
                    userDone = true;
                }
                else if(input == 5 && !grid.previousInputs.contains(input))
                {
                    grid.previousInputs.add(input);
                    g2.draw(X5s1);
                    g2.draw(X5s2);
                    userDone = true;
                }
                else if(input == 6 && !grid.previousInputs.contains(input))
                {
                    grid.previousInputs.add(input);
                    g2.draw(X6s1);
                    g2.draw(X6s2);
                    userDone = true;
                }
                else if(input == 7 && !grid.previousInputs.contains(input))
                {
                    grid.previousInputs.add(input);
                    g2.draw(X7s1);
                    g2.draw(X7s2);
                    userDone = true;
                }
                else if(input == 8 && !grid.previousInputs.contains(input))
                {
                    grid.previousInputs.add(input);
                    g2.draw(X8s1);
                    g2.draw(X8s2);
                    userDone = true;
                }
                else if(input == 9 && !grid.previousInputs.contains(input))
                {
                    grid.previousInputs.add(input);
                    g2.draw(X9s1);
                    g2.draw(X9s2);
                    userDone = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    g2.drawString("Input Error: Please input a number 1 - 9", 200, 30);
                    userDone = false;
                }
            }

            while(userDone)
            {
                if(!grid.previousInputs.contains(5))
                {
                   g2.draw(O5);
                   grid.previousInputs.add(5);
                   userDone = false;
                }
                else if(!grid.previousInputs.contains(1))
                {
                    g2.draw(O1);
                    grid.previousInputs.add(1);
                    userDone = false;
                }
                else if(!grid.previousInputs.contains(3))
                {
                    g2.draw(O3);
                    grid.previousInputs.add(3);
                    userDone = false;
                }
                else if(!grid.previousInputs.contains(7))
                {
                    g2.draw(O7);
                    grid.previousInputs.add(7);
                    userDone = false;
                }
                else if(!grid.previousInputs.contains(9))
                {
                    g2.draw(O9);
                    grid.previousInputs.add(9);
                    userDone = false;
                }
                else if(!grid.previousInputs.contains(2))
                {
                    g2.draw(O2);
                    grid.previousInputs.add(2);
                    userDone = false;
                } 
                else if(!grid.previousInputs.contains(4))
                {
                    g2.draw(O4);
                    grid.previousInputs.add(4);
                    userDone = false;
                }
                else if(!grid.previousInputs.contains(6))
                {
                    g2.draw(O6);
                    grid.previousInputs.add(6);
                    userDone = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    g2.draw(O8);
                    grid.previousInputs.add(8);
                    g2.drawString("Game Over!", 200, 230);
                }

            }
```

Comment: What do you mean "The computer responds?" What part of the code is that?

Comment: Somewhere along the lines you are setting userDone to true

Comment: @Kryanstar I mean that the user puts an X somewhere, and then the computer puts an O somewhere.

Comment: @NightSky Any help on where that might be?

Comment: Is anyone going to help me?

Comment: First thing, define some functions to simplify the logic. The only reason you would need to write 10 branches of the if-else logic in the first half of the program is because you haven't defined a function `drawXinCellNumber(int cellnumber)`.  The computer's turn also should not require so many branches, although your strategy does require specifying the order of preference in which cell it will fill first. MOST IMPORTANTLY: find out about the debugger in your development environment and learn how to use it.

Comment: @DavidK I use Eclipse but I have no idea how to use debugger, I have tried but I didn't do it correctly. Also, this is a program that is due tomorrow, I am totally stuck and I really need help. I see what you are saying but I just want to keep the way I have it and fix it.

Comment: Sorry, I looked carefully but couldn't see the error in the program. _Please_ get someone to show you how to use the debugger, especially if this is not your last assignment in this class.  It may be the most useful skill you get out of the entire course.